# Firebase Admin multiple account per email address

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Is there a way to specify the provider when I use `admin.auth().createUser()`.
Indeed in my case a user can choose to use **email/password**, or a specific **OAuth provider**

Here is what it looks like in Firebase Console :

[image]

Here is my code to create email/password account :

```
Firebase.getAuth(dbInfos).createUser({email: "toto@mail.fr", password: "qwerty"});
```

Here is my code to create OAuth account :

```
Firebase.getAuth(dbInfos).createUser({uid: "my:specific:uid", email: "toto@mail.fr"});
```

But when a user already have a email/password account, I can't create the specific OAuth account with the same email address. I need this cause want to offer multiple auth way for the same user.

This my configuration :
[image]

Some month ago it was working, but nowadays it doesn't work.
Thansk in advance

Comment: You can't currently create an OAuth account via Admin SDK.

Comment: In fact my account is not really OAuth, it's "no provider" account, from Firebase perspective. But OK, I think I can't do what I want. Thanks for your answer.